# PHP Array merge explode

Tags: php, arrays

I have some fields that recives content from various inputs.

```
$fields = array();

if (!empty($_POST['field1'])) {
 $fields = explode(',', $_POST['field1']);
 // receives: foo1, foo2
}

if (!empty($_POST['field2'])) {
 $fields = explode(',', $_POST['field2']);
 //receives: foo3, foo4, foo5
}

if (!empty($_POST['field3'])) {
 $fields = explode(',', $_POST['field3']);
 //receives: foo6
}

// Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 ) 
// Array ( [0] => foo3 [1] => foo4 [2] => foo5 )
// Array ( [0] => foo6 )
```

And I would like to get them into a simple Array.

```
//Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 [5] => foo6 )
```

Comment: Hint: `array_merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in several ways:

**Way 1 - [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

```
$fields = array();

if (!empty($_POST['field1'])) {
 $fields = explode(',', $_POST['field1']);
 // receives: foo1, foo2
}

if (!empty($_POST['field2'])) {
 $fields = array_merge($fields, explode(',', $_POST['field2']));
 //receives: foo3, foo4, foo5
}

if (!empty($_POST['field3'])) {
 $fields = array_merge($fields, explode(',', $_POST['field3']));
 //receives: foo6
}
```

**Way 2 - [array_push](https://prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)**

```
$fields = array();

if (!empty($_POST['field1'])) {
 $fields = explode(',', $_POST['field1']);
 // receives: foo1, foo2
}

if (!empty($_POST['field2'])) {
    foreach (explode(',', $_POST['field2']) as $val) {
      array_push($fields, $val);
    }
    //receives: foo3, foo4, foo5
}

if (!empty($_POST['field3'])) {
    foreach (explode(',', $_POST['field3']) as $val) {
      array_push($fields, $val);
    }
   //receives: foo6
}
```

Comment: The second example doesn't produce the same result. The pieces from `field2` and `field3` will be arrays themselves, thus producing a multidimensional array.

Comment: @El_Vanja I changed the answer, ty for your comment

Comment: Even after the update, it will still produce a multidimensional array (and you have a syntax error, you forgot to close the outer parenthesis). Test the code before posting. You would need to use the spread operator `...` on the result of `explode` to make it work properly.